# Android: which layouts/widgets use to reach such an effect

Tags: android

Please I need to recreate an layout similar to the following:

- A List (a ListView?) with the hours of the day
- inside each item of the list should be possible to dynamically add sub elements.

Please any advice very much helpful.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add `Android:` to your question titles, the tag at the bottom is more than enough. There's nothing stopping you from using a `ListView` and adding the necessary views in the `getView()` method(remember to revert this row if it gets recycled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with an `ExpandableListView` where each hour will be a child of `ExpandableListView` and they will have custom layout for their own children which includes a `TextView` and an image next to it - you don't have to add an extra `ImageView` since you can set that image with `android:drawableRight` attribute of `TextView`-
With `ExpandableListView` you can also open/close each hour child.

Take a look at this tutorial for `ExpandableListView`

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/